# Non-normal residuals - P-values higher or lower?

Tags: regression, p-value, residuals, normality-assumption

**Background:**

I have estimated a model using panel data with the Arellano Bond estimator (see e.g., http://www.fordham.edu/economics/mcleod/Elitz-usingArellano%E2%80%93BondGMMEstimators.pdf) and n=300. As it turns out, the distribution of my residuals is significantly different from the normal wrt. skewness and kurtosis.

**Question:**

Is it possible/how can I infer whether the calculated p-values should be higher or lower given the information available (dist, sd., kurtosis, skewness, etc.)?

I hope my question is sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 1):

1 – non-normal residuals might indicate poor model fit. Panel-GMM models are quite tricky, something might be wrong with you specification.

2 – Have you tried the robust standard error calculation methods?

Comment: 1 - Yes, that's true. Problem is that I have a lack of relevant data to correct for it, and need some tip of whether or not my inference now is likely to be "less valid" when correcting. 2 - Yes.